# Changing a `Published` property of an `ObservableObject` to a computed var

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject, property-wrapper-published

I have an `ObservableObject` with `@Published` properties:

```swift
class SettingsViewState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var viewData: SettingsViewData = .init()
    …
```

I would like to change `viewData` to a computed var based on other sources of truth rather than allowing it to be directly modified. However, I still want views looking at `viewData` to automatically update as it changes. They should update when properties it is computed from change.

I'm really not very certain about how `@Published` actually works though. I *think* it has its `willSet` perform `objectWillChange.send()` on the **enclosing** `ObservableObject` before a change occurs, but I'm not sure!

If my suspicion is correct, it seems like I could manually call `objectWillChange.send()` on the enclosing object if anything `viewData` depends on will change.

Alternatively, if properties `viewData` is computed from are themself `@Published`, when I change one, presumably an equivalent `objectWillChange.send()` will occur automatically, and I won't need to do anything special? This should work even if these properties are `private` and a watching view doesn't have access to them: it should still see the `objectWillChange` being emitted?

However, It's entirely possible I've got this horribly garbled or mostly backwards! Eg, perhaps the `@Published` properties have their own independent change publisher, rather than simply making use of the enclosing `ObservableObject`'s? Or both of them publish prior to a change?

Clarification will be gratefully received. Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). "They should update when properties it is computed from change" How about making the "properties it is computed from" `@Published` instead? You can then use `combineLatest` to combines all of those properties.

Comment: Alternatively, how about making `SettingsViewData` itself an `ObservableObject`? And it would have all the "properties it is computed from". Assuming that it is/can be made into a class, of course.

Comment: "it seems like I could manually call `objectWillChange.send()` on the enclosing object if anything `viewData` depends on will change." "...and I won't need to do anything special?" Did you try anything to verify these suspicions? These sounds like they can be easily verified by just writing some code.

Comment: I'm not wildly happy with the tone of your responses here @Sweeper, if you don't have time for this question, please do skip it, and thank you. If you can clearly see I'm confused, which is likely, please try to educate me (and others) gently. Thank you for your time though! In terms of validating, I can write a test to validate this current element of behaviour, but this will only confirm if it happens to work, not whether it is the intended use pattern of the system. I'm after that deeper understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm really not very certain about how @Published actually works though. I think it has its willSet perform objectWillChange.send() on the enclosing ObservableObject before a change occurs, but I'm not sure!

You are correct, that is how `@Published` and `ObservableObject` work together, however, these are 2 independent things.

`@Published` is a property wrapper, which adds a `Publisher` to the wrapped property, which emits the new value from the `willSet` of the property. So the `Published.Publisher` emits the value that is about to be set before it is actually set.

`ObservableObject` is a protocol, which has an `objectWillChange` publisher, whose value is autosynthesised by the compiler. The synthesised implementation emits a value when any of the `@Published` property's publishers emits. So `objectWillChange` emits a value whenever an `@Published` property on the `ObservableObject` conformant type is about to change.

If you store an `ObservableObject` conformant type on a SwiftUI `View` as `@StateObject`, `@ObservedObject` or `@EnvironmentObject`, the view updates (and hence recalculates its `body`) whenever the `objectWillChange` of the `ObservableObject` emits.

If you have a property, which needs to be recalculated whenever other properties are updated and you want to update your view with these changes, you have several options to achieve that.

1. Declare all properties as stored `@Published` properties and set up the dependant property to be updated whenever any of the properties it depends on are updated.

This 100% guarantees that your view will always be updated with the correct values and you don't need to call `objectWillChange.send()` manually.

This solution also works even if the properties that your "computed" property depends on are declared on other types, since your "computed" property is `@Published` so whenever it is updated, it will trigger a view update.

However, you do need to set up the observation of your dependant properties to update the property that depends on them.

```
@Published var height: Int
@Published var width: Int

@Published private(set) var size: Int

init(height: Int, width: Int) {
  self.height = height
  self.width = width
  self.size = height * width
  $height.combineLatest($width).map { height, width in
    height * width
  }.assign(to: &$size)
}
```

2. If all all properties that your computed property depend on are `@Published` and are declared on the same object as your computed property, simply declaring the property that depends on them as computed should work, since the properties that you depend on will trigger a view update themselves whenever they are updated.

This doesn't work though if your `@Published` properties are declared on another object, since that object won't trigger a view update.

Comment: Thank you! That's extremely helpful, gives a lot of insight to what's going on, and points me to a solution. I prefer option 2 here, I think. My reasoning is: With option 1 I think it is easy to accidentally omit code that should update a dependent property (especially during code evolution). In contrast, with approach 2, update code is not needed and so cannot be forgotten?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@State` for view data (values or structs with mutating funcs). `ObservableObject` was originally designed for model data lifetime.

In the View struct use a computed property to transform the data as you pass it down to child `View` structs. Usually we transform from rich model types to simple values that get passed into previewable Views.

The more recent addition of `@StateObject` is for when you need a reference type in an `@State` which is uncommon and doesn't seem to be the need here.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer? It seems like you are suggesting not having a separate model and maintaining this as state of views?

Comment: There is a store object to hold the model data usually environmentObject. View data is  in the `View` structs, `let` for read and `@State var` or `@Binding var` for read/write. Computed var to transform. SwiftUI will diff your structs and use the diff to create/update/remove UIView objects for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to answer this same question for myself and landed here. I know it's been "solved" for a couple of months now, but I found another way that works for my scenario, at least.

Instead of making the public property computed, you can put the work on the private properties to update the public one whenever they are updated using their `didSet`.

```swift
import Foundation
    
class ThemeList: ObservableObject {
    // this is the property I wanted to be computed
    @Published public private(set) var themes: [String]
        
    // these are the "sources of truth"
    private let internalThemes: [String]
    private var customThemes: [String] {
        // this is where the magic happens!
        didSet {
            bundleThemes()
        }        
    }
    
    init(themes: [String], customThemes: [String] = []) {
        self.internalThemes = themes
        self.customThemes = customThemes
        self.themes = []
        bundleThemes()
    }
    
    // set the (no-longer computed) @Published property
    // triggering the 
    func bundleThemes() {
        var allThemes: [String]
        allThemes = internalThemes
        allThemes.append(contentsOf: customThemes)
        allThemes.sort()
        themes = allThemes
    }
    
    func addTheme(_ theme: String) {
        customThemes.append(theme)
    }
}
    
let themeList = ThemeList(themes: ["Hi", "Hello"])
let cancellable = themeList.$themes
    .sink() {
        print ($0)
}
    
themeList.addTheme("Howdy!")
```

You can run that as-is in a playground and see that the new value `["Hi", "Hello", "Howdy!"]` gets published.

Originally, I was trying to make `themes` a computed property that would combine and sort two private properties (internal and custom themes). Of course you can't use `@Published` on a computed property. So instead you make it public get, private set property and use `didSet` to update it. This has the effect of keeping the property updated as if it were computed and also emitting the change notification.